# Pandas - pivoting table with year row and week column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

```
|      | Public transport | Public transport.1 | Taxis | Taxis.1 |
| ---- | ---------------- | ------------------ | ----- | ------- |
| year | 2019             | 2020               | 2019  | 2020    |
| W1   | 100.0            | 91.3               | 100.0 | 102.1   |
| W2   | 91.1             | 96.6               | 98.3  | 88.3    |
```

I want to `transpose`, `pivot`, `stack`/`unstack` to get a table like this:

```
| year | week | Public transport | Taxis |
| ---- | ---- | ---------------- | ----- |
| 2019 | W1   | 100.0            | 100.0 |
|      | W2   | 91.1             | 98.3  |
| 2020 | W1   | 91.3             | 102.1 |
|      | W2   | 96.6             | 88.3  |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
out = (
    df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split(".").str[0], axis=1).T.astype({"year": int})
        .melt(ignore_index=False, id_vars="year", var_name="week").reset_index()
        .pivot(index=["year", "week"], columns="index", values="value")
        .rename_axis(columns=None)# with optional `.reset_index()`
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

           Public transport  Taxis
year week                         
2019 W1              100.00 100.00
     W2               91.10  98.30
2020 W1               91.30 102.10
     W2               96.60  88.30
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Public transport': {'year': 2019.0, 'W1': 100.0, 'W2': 91.1},
     'Public transport.1': {'year': 2020.0, 'W1': 91.3, 'W2': 96.6},
     'Taxis': {'year': 2019.0, 'W1': 100.0, 'W2': 98.3},
     'Taxis.1': {'year': 2020.0, 'W1': 102.1, 'W2': 88.3}}
)
```

Answer (score 4):

As alternative of @Timeless, I suppose your data comes from an excel or csv file (cause colname.1) so perhaps you can read your file with some other parameters:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=[0, 1], index_col=0)
# OR
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=[0, 1], index_col=0)

out = df.rename_axis('week').stack().swaplevel().sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     Public transport        Taxis       
year             2019  2020   2019   2020
W1              100.0  91.3  100.0  102.1
W2               91.1  96.6   98.3   88.3

>>> out
           Public transport  Taxis
year week                         
2019 W1               100.0  100.0
     W2                91.1   98.3
2020 W1                91.3  102.1
     W2                96.6   88.3

>>> out.reset_index()
   year week  Public transport  Taxis
0  2019   W1             100.0  100.0
1  2019   W2              91.1   98.3
2  2020   W1              91.3  102.1
3  2020   W2              96.6   88.3
```